# jquery on search hide not hiding all occurance of an id

Tags: jquery, findall

i'm using

`$(list).find("#disappear").hide();`

to hide my title **on search**. It's working but it's hiding only first occurrence of li with id disappear. It's not hiding all content having #disappear

Did anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Multiple elements having same id is invalid, please fix your markup. As @Harshit mentioned use a class rather than an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class instend of ID beacause all id attribute values are unique on the web page.

```
$(list).find(".disappear").hide();
```

Comment: @Vin_fugen Please consider green-checking this answer if it served your purpose. and don't forgot to up vote.